# Find the value of $\tan^2\alpha+\cot^2\beta$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

A circle with centre o have two chords AC and BD,which are intersecting each other at P.If $\angle AOB=15^\circ$ and $\angle APB=30^\circ$,then find out value of 
$$\tan^2\angle APB+\cot^2\angle COD$$

I want to do it as quick as possible this is an objective question so there is no need to  describe steps.

Comment: But you already know the value of $\tan^2 \angle APB$ don't you?

Comment: yes it is $\dfrac13$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $\angle COD = 45^\circ$ (or $315^\circ$, depending on how you measure it). As John mentioned, we know $\angle APB = 30^\circ$.

This is the quickest way, and I've not described any steps like you requested.

Comment: Yeah, that's right and you can find that value of $\angle COD$ using just simple euclidean geometry.

Comment: Indeed. It's very direct, 1 paragraph.

Comment: Sorry i'm not getting it. I've now $\angle CPD=30^\circ,\angle APD=\angle BPC= 150^\circ$.Now what should i do

Comment: Join $BC$ and you have $\angle ABC$ is half of $\angle AOB$ as they are subtended by the same arc. Now as $\angle BPC=150$, $\angle CBD=22.5$ (angle sum of triangle). But $\angle COD$ is twice $\angle CBD$ subtended by same arc and is thus $45$.

Comment: Note the essential theorem you need here is that an angle subtended at the center of a circle is twice the size of the angle subtended by the same arc at the circle's circumference.

Comment: I know this theorem but I didn't figure it out where to apply in question

Comment: @iostream007 Another hint is that $180^\circ - \angle APB = \angle CAB + \angle DBA = \frac{1}{2} \ldots $.